# Transparency lost after IE7 Transform

Tags: jquery, transform

I'm creating a page targeting IE7. On a section of the page, the user can rotate and zoom in and out of an area (div element) containing a background image and a number of other programmatically added divs. The non-image divs are empty but styled with css to have a position, color and transparency. They act to highlight areas of the image based on user actions.

I am using the jQuery 2D Transformation Plugin from here:
https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki
to do the rotation and scaling/zooming. I'm using a lot of other javascript and jquery to handle user interactions.

Everything is working fine except for one thing: When the user scales or rotates the div, the transparency of the highlight divs is lost. They rotate and scale with the parent div and image perfectly, but the color becomes opaque and muddy. It's as though the area behind the highlight went black or something.

Anyone have any idea what I can do about that? I've tried reapplying the css styles via javascript after the transformation. I can change the color of the divs, but changing the transparency just makes the div more or less muddy - it never becomes transparent again.

A possibly simpler question: is it possible to remove a Transform created with this library? If that's possible, then maybe I can reset everything when the user moves back to 100% scale and non-rotated. That wouldn't be ideal, but would be better than the current situation.

Comment: Is it possible the divs are losing hasLayout when they are rotated? Try adding a `zoom:1` style and see if it still happens, or use the IE developer tools to check if the hasLayout property is set after the divs have been rotated. 
Some sample code would make it much easier for us to help, since we could then see what's physically happening.

Comment: @KelvinMackay hasLayout remains set on all of the elements with a value of -1. I didn't know about the IE developer tools - thank you VERY much for that. I don't normally target IE-only so I normally use FF to diagnose problems. The code base is pretty huge right now. If I can figure out a way to make it smaller, I'll post something.

Comment: You'll probably also find the free DynaTrace AJAX Edition helpful for general IE development, although I don't think it will be much help with this particular problem. http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ajax-performance-testing.html
Just a thought - I don't know how to solve your problem I'm afraid, but from what you're describing the elements that are giving you problems are just coloured divs with say 25% opacity - perhaps you could use a semitransparent PNG as the background image of each div instead to achieve the same effect and possibly sidestep the problem?

Comment: @KelvinMackay: Using a PNG as the background image works perfectly. THANK YOU! If you'd like to submit that as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to help. When dealing with IE the solution always seems to be a workaround rather than a fix, but as long as it gets the job done eh? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer per our conversation in the question comments :)

From what you're describing the elements that are giving you problems are just coloured divs with say 25% opacity. You could use a semitransparent PNG as the background image of each div instead to achieve the same effect and sidestep the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a jQuery library, to remove a css rule, simply pass it an empty string.

```
$('selector').css('transform', '');
```

Comment: That helped. `$("#el").css('filter', '');` allows me to remove the transformation (or filter?) when rotation and zoom are normal. Still hoping to find a way to have the transparency when the element is rotated or scaled.

Comment: It will remove any CSS rule applied via javascript